# Defer component initialization until jwt token available in local storage

Tags: angular, socket.io

I'm building an Angular app together with a node.js rest api.
I'm also using socket.io for some websocket stuff like providing progress updates.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-socket-io documents the possibility to provide `options : {}` when initializing. I haven't found a way to add options other than calling a constructor (i.e. during runtime)

The angular app provides a user interface to authenticate with the backend, and upon successful authentication a jwt token is returned and stored in local storage.

How can I defer the injection of the service component wrapping ngx-socket-io until the jwt token is available in the clients local storage?

The answer need not be specific to ngx-socket-io, it could be any component dependent on some async call before it can be initialized.

Comment: Question is too vague. Please share minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I would prefer not, since it is more a question about the architecture of Angular. Is it e.g. https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers#using-factory-providers that is the canonical way to solve this, or something else?